# How to concatenate two array values into a sibling key/value pair of a JS object

Tags: javascript, oop

Doing some fiddly webpack configuration and don't know how to get two arrays into a new array within the SAME js object. Can anyone see the problem? I want **sass.fileNames.public** *and* **sass.fileNames.private** to be concatenated and create **sass.all** which would look like

> ['styles', 'print', 'custom', 'screen']

```js
var sass = {
    fileNames:{
        public:['styles', 'print'],
        private:['custom', 'screen'],
        all: this.fileNames.public.concat(this.fileNames.private),
    },
    filePaths:{
        // PUBLIC WEBSITE STYLESHEETS
        public:{
            entry: './entry-path',
        },
        // ADMIN PRIVATE STYLESHEETS
        private:{
            entry: './entry',
        },
    },
    fileType: ".scss", // Can be changed to .sass or .scss depending on format used
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I just see a solution by putting the public and private outside of your object and concat it inside

```js
var public = ['styles', 'print'],
    private = ['custom', 'screen'];
 var sass = {
    fileNames:{
        public:public,
        private:private,
        all: public.concat(private),
    },
    filePaths:{
        // PUBLIC WEBSITE STYLESHEETS
        public:{
            entry: './entry-path',
        },
        // ADMIN PRIVATE STYLESHEETS
        private:{
            entry: './entry',
        },
    },
    fileType: ".scss", // Can be changed to .sass or .scss depending on format used
};
console.log(sass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you concat it after the defination? Like this..

```js
var sass = {
    fileNames:{
        public:['styles', 'print'],
        private:['custom', 'screen'],
        //all: this.fileNames.public.concat(this.fileNames.private),
    },
    filePaths:{
        // PUBLIC WEBSITE STYLESHEETS
        public:{
            entry: './entry-path',
        },
        // ADMIN PRIVATE STYLESHEETS
        private:{
            entry: './entry',
        },
    },
    fileType: ".scss", // Can be changed to .sass or .scss depending on format used
};

sass.fileNames.all = sass.fileNames.public.concat(sass.fileNames.private);


console.log(JSON.stringify(sass))
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that will work, it's how I have it currently. I just wanted to streamline it some more and didn't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to setup a function on the object to perform what you have intend to do, because the function have 'this' applied to it, the function can then return 'this' and delete itself in order to disable further usage.

```
var sass = {
    fileNames:{
        public:['styles', 'print'],
        private:['custom', 'screen'],
    },
    filePaths:{
        // PUBLIC WEBSITE STYLESHEETS
        public:{
            entry: './entry-path',
        },
        // ADMIN PRIVATE STYLESHEETS
        private:{
            entry: './entry',
        },
    },
    fileType: ".scss", // Can be changed to .sass or .scss depending on format used,

    updateAllFileNames: function(){

        // set values as you want
        this.fileNames.all = Array.prototype.concat.apply(
            this.fileNames.public,
            this.fileNames.private
        )

        // delete the function so it will not be usable anymore
        delete this.updateAllFileNames

        // return self in order to assign the sass object
        return this;
    }
}.updateAllFileNames()
```

Comment: That will work but it's more verbose than I currently have, doing the assignment outside of the object.

Comment: I agree, still, the answer is relevant to how to do it withing the same object according to the question